# How to check if a string or a number exists inside an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a functions which asks the users to write their favorites animals ant then stores it in an array called animals.When a user executes the function I want to check if the animal he wants is inside the array and if yes to show the index of the animal(for example:The animal you entered is already in the array.Its index number is...).Any ideas?

```
var animals=[]
function anim(){
var ani=prompt("Give me an animal you like");
animals.push(ani);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var animals= new Array('dog');
var ani=prompt("Give me an animal you like");
if(animals.indexOf(ani) >= 0 ){
    alert(animals.indexOf(ani));


}else{
   animals.push(ani);
}
```

[JsFillde Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/93tegwzf/)

Comment: As a side note, to support IE8<, you should use jQuery `$.inArray()` method instead: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/  or any `Array.prototype.indexOf` polyfill

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate across the array and with regex to get accurate result regard less input case

```
 function searchArr(arr, q){      
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        patt = new RegExp(q,"i");
        if (patt.test(arr[i])) return i;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Testing Code:

```
 animals = new Array('dog', 'cat', 'camel', 'deer');
    q = prompt("Enter Animal Name");
    r = searchArr(animals,q);
    alert(r)
    if (r || r ===0){
      alert("Animal found and its index " + r)
    }
    else{
      alert("Not found")
    }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jolaqiduka/1/

Answer (score 1):

This this way

```
var animals=[]

function anim() {
   var ani = prompt("Give me an animal you like");

   // The function returns a position of an input element (in array) begins from the 0
   // or -1 if the element is not exists in the array
   if (animals.indexOf(ani) > -1)
       alert('Already in');
   else
       animals.push(ani);
}
```

Next fiddle may help: http://jsfiddle.net/8g5gpqx2/

Answer (score 1):

you can find out if a value is inside of an array by using `indexOf()`.

for example: `animals.indexOf('dog');`

this will return the index of the string 'dog'. if it doesn't exist, it will return a value of -1.